# I cannot hide text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, hidden

I am having trouble hiding an item with javascript. I have included the code below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJqZd.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnr7v.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHNLk.png

Comment: Your images contain copyable text... just copy paste it into the actual question, there is even a code `{}` button to help format it. Also as a hint: javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<div>
<h2 id="test">About me</h2>
</div>

<script>
window.onload = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
   var element = document.getElementById('test');
element.style.display = 'none'; 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Andrew Breeze-Stringfellow try This

Answer (score 0):

window.onLoad should be  window.onload in your functions.js file.
**JavaScript is Case Sensitive**